# Script to update all package managers

Tags: rubygems, npm, pip, homebrew, bower

Was wondering if there is a gist script to update all the possible package managers you have installed.

Off the top of my head I currently use

- npm
- pip
- gem
- brew
- brew cask
- bower

I think I have a few more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found one it does homebrew, apt-get, gems, pip packages, and node packages.

https://gist.github.com/jfrazelle/57dbf1fccfa02151ff3f

I'll have to see if I can add bower to it.

**EDIT**

my current alias

```
alias update='sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; brew upgrade --all; brew cleanup; brew cask cleanup; brew prune; npm update -g npm; npm update -g; sudo composer self-update; composer global update; sudo gem update --system;gem update; gem cleanup; meteor update;'
```

covers

- osx update
- brew + cask + cleanup
- npm
- gem
- meteor
- composer

**EDIT**

Added python

```
alias update='sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; brew upgrade --all; brew cleanup; brew cask cleanup; brew prune; npm update -g npm; npm update -g; sudo gem update --system; gem update; gem cleanup; pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U; meteor update; sudo composer self-update; composer global update;'
```

**EDIT**

Added perl

```
alias update='sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; brew upgrade --all; brew cleanup; brew cask cleanup; brew prune; npm update -g npm; npm update -g; sudo gem update --system; gem update; gem cleanup; pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U; sudo composer self-update; composer global update; perlbrew self-upgrade; perlbrew upgrade-perl; perlbrew clean; cpan -u; meteor update;'
```

**EDIT**

Created a custom script for the perl update (`perlbrew upgrade-perl` doesn't seem to work, **used above**)

```
alias update='sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; brew upgrade --all; brew cleanup; brew cask cleanup; brew prune; npm update -g npm; npm update -g; sudo gem update --system; gem update; gem cleanup; pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U; sudo composer self-update; composer global update; . updatePerl; cpan -u; meteor update;'
```

**EDIT**

Added ruby

Create a custom script to update ruby version (rbenv doesn't seem to `update to latest`)

```
alias update='sudo softwareupdate -i -a; brew update; brew upgrade --all; brew cleanup; brew cask cleanup; brew prune; npm update -g npm; npm update -g; updateRuby; sudo gem update --system; gem update; gem cleanup; pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U; sudo composer self-update; composer global update; . updatePerl; cpan -u; meteor update;'
```

### Resourses

[Gist link](https://gist.github.com/privatmamtora/fcfd3a1076b58ab4de37)

[updatePerl](https://gist.github.com/privatmamtora/75c74cc937d54c3620ac)
[updateRuby](https://gist.github.com/privatmamtora/333e55cdc64fcbce4ff5)

Comment: The gist seems to be offline now.

Comment: @kennysong I added a new link to my gist